# Spontaneous breaking of discrete symmetry in d=1+1 at finite temperature and infinite volume

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, temperature, symmetry-breaking

I came across the question of SSB of a discrete symmetry (say, $\mathbb{Z}_2$) symmetry in a QFT in d=1+1 dimensions, at finite temperature, and I have trouble making sense of two different viewpoints which seem to lead to contradicting results. Can you point me to the fallacy in my reasoning?

Let us assume that at zero temperature, at infinite volume, (that is, on $\mathbb{R}^2$, in an Euclidean setting) the  $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is spontaneously broken (for instance, as a consequence of an 't Hooft anomaly). Let us also assume that the first excitations on top of each vacuum are gapped with mass $M$.
Finite temperature means periodic Euclidean time, $\tau\sim\tau+\beta$. This turns our (Euclidean) spacetime manifold into $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$. One observable that is sensitive to SSB is the Euclidean partition function $Z_E(\beta)$: the leading order in the large $\beta$ expansion will give us the ground state degeneracy.

**Viewpoint 1**: Let us quantize the theory on the line. The full Hilbert space on the line splits in 2 superselection sectors, $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_0\oplus\mathcal{H}_1$, and states on each sector are obtained by adding excitations on top of the respective vacuum. The two sectors are exactly identical. At leading order, then, we would find $Z_E(\beta)= 2 + O(e^{-\beta M})$, where $M$ is the gap.

**Viewpoint 2**: Let us quantize the theory on the circle. This is equivalent to studying a QFT in finite volume and zero temperature. Being the volume finite, there cannot be SSB. There is a unique invariant ground state, let us call it $|+\rangle$.
(There is also another state, $|-\rangle$, almost degenerate to it. The gap between the two can be obtained à la Coleman: $\Delta E=K e^{-S_0}$, where $S_0$ is the instanton action, and  $S_0=\beta m$, since I expect the instanton (of mass $m$) to be invariant under rotation in the compact direction. $K$ is a dimensionful constant that depends on the details of the theory.)
Let us now try to argue for the behavior of $Z_E(\beta)$. Indeed, we now should compute ${\rm Tr}\, e^{-LH}$, in the limit $L\to\infty$ (here $L$ is interpreted as inverse temperature, which is taken to infinity since we want to end up on the infinite cylinder). No matter what, however, only the ground state will contribute in this limit, and $Z_E(\beta)\sim 1$.

**My intuition** for the resolution to the contradiction would be the following: Viewpoint 1 is right and Viewpoint 2 is wrong, because the limit $L\to\infty$ is discontinuous, and if I kept $L$ finite and then sent it to infinity also in Viewpoint 1 I would have obtained the same (wrong) answer. However, I do not see a way to fix Viewpoint 2 in such a way to give the correct result, if such a way exists.

Is this it? Or am I being wrong in both cases?

Comment: Both should be right. The issue in viewpoint 2 is that the splitting should be $\Delta E \sim e^{-m L}$, so the two states become degenerate as $L\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks for the comment! Could you please elaborate a bit more on how it is so? I would have said that the almost-degenerate state has $\Delta E\sim e^{-\beta m}$, and not $\sim e^{-Lm}$, since I would not expect the energy of states on $S^1$ to depend at all on the size of the other direction.